# jQuery nextAll and prevAll "successors" and "predecessors"

Tags: jquery, terminology

The [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/)   for `nextAll()` and `prevAll()` refers to "successors" and "predecessors".  Is my understanding correct that they must be *sibling* elements in the same container element?

For example, you couldn't have a PianoKeyboard `div` element containing multiple Octave `div` elements each containing multiple PianoKey `p` elements, and then, while on a PianoKey, use `nextAll` or `prevAll` to visit all successor or predecessor keys within the current Octave and move seamlessly on to vist PianoKeys in an *adjacent* Octave?

To visit keys in more than octave, you would need nested loops and would have to test to see if you were at the first or final PianoKey in the Octave, whereupon you would have to "leap" to the adjacent Octave, is that right?

Comment: `Is my understanding correct that they must be sibling elements in the same container element?` Yes. The documentation states this explicitly: 'Get all following ***siblings*** of each element in the set of matched elements'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan:  And it is not possible to fetch the successor Octaves, merging their respective PianoKey children sets into a single set, then prepend the current Octave's successor PianoKeys to that set, and then visit each successor PianoKey in turn?

Comment: @Tim of course that's possible, but not with `$("p.key").prevAll()` - why don't you ask the question you want to know the answer to?

Comment: If you want both all successors *and* all predecessors then use `.siblings()`, but I still don't think that's what you want to ask.

Comment: Depending on where you start ("next" being relative):  `$(this).closest("div.keyboard").find("p.key")` will give you all the keys across all the octaves.  You can then loop through them, or make changes to the set as one.

Comment: @freedomn-m:  I want to have a good understanding of how nextAll works before formulating my question.  I basically want to "glissando" the keyboard and the fact that the nextAll and prevAll are restricted to siblings (intra-Octave) has me looking for hacks. Thank you for "closest", I will try it out!

Comment: @freedomn-m: You see, when I read the documentation, I don't even know what the word "up" means, as in "Closest() travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector".  Does "up" mean going from PianoKey to Octave (the container/parent) and looking for a match for PianoKey at the Octave level?

Comment: @freedomn-m : .... or looking for a match for PianoKey *within* the Octave level?

Comment: It goes "up" from wherever you start.  Most, if not all, of the DOM traversal methods need a starting point.  So if `this` is a key, then `$(this).parent()` will go "up" to an octave, while if `this` is already an octave then `$(this).parent()` will be the keyboard.

Comment: I'm assuming keyboard/octave/key is just a way to understand the concepts.  Breaking a keyboard into octaves wouldn't really be a good idea in general, eg which key would you start on A?  or C?

Comment: If you're trying to *step* the keys, then you would use `.next()`, .nextAll would give you *all* the remaining keys in that octave.  So you would have a loop checking `key = key.next()` and when it returns `key == null` you would then do `key = key.closest(".octave").find(".key").first()` to get the "next" key in the next octave.   I tend to use `.closest` as it's more flexible, eg if you change to `octave > GMajorNotes > keys` then `.closest(".octave")` will still find the octave, while `.parent()` will break.

Comment: If you want all the keys regardless of which octave they're in then you can do `$(".key")` or, if you want to be more specific `$(".octave .key")` then loop that collection using .each or similar.

Comment: Thanks.  Using `closest` in some manner might do. In `keydown` event I want to move focus to the *adjacent* key according to whether LeftArrow or RightArrow was pressed.  Sometimes the key will be a sibling key within the current octave and sometimes a "cousin" key in an adjacent octave, either the *last* key in the next lower octave or the *first* key in the next higher octave.   So I'll need to find one of the key's uncle or aunt octaves and get the appropriate cousin key.